# Binding click in Bootstrap's popover using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have an issue binding click of  element that located within Bootstrap's popover.

**Html**

```
<a href="#" id="open-popover-link">Open popover</a>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
<a href="#" data-bind="click: Click">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

**Knockout**

```
 function Model() {
        var self = this;
        self.Click = function () {
            alert('Works!');
        }
```

For some reason this doesn't work, but if I move  tag out of popover, it works. Where is the problem here?

Comment: Bootstrap _probably_ adds and removes the popover to/from the DOM dynamically. This means knockout looses track of the data-binds. You'll have to find a way to either A) keep/reuse the original data-bound element or B) re-apply data-binds after the DOM injection

Comment: bootstrap does not use your existing DOM (and events) to display the popover it copies it and displays the copy which means the click event tied to the original DOM elements will not fire.  Solution is to tie into the popover fire event and rebind the vm to the newly created dom at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets generally have their own ways of modifying the DOM. For such things, you need [Custom Binding Handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). There are a number of binding handlers that have already been written for commonly-used widgets like jQuery-UI and Bootstrap.

[Knockstrap](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#popover) is a collection of binding for Bootstrap widgets (including the popover).